# Is it possible to store generated EMF model directly to CDO?

Tags: eclipse-emf, cdo-emf

From the document that I have followed, I understood that every element in EMF model to extend CDOObject. Is this mandatory to extend CDOObject? If yes, then I have an EMF model which is actually developed from other team and don't have permission to extend model class CDOObject. Is there any alternative solution in such case??

Answer (score 0):

Using pure EMF-Models with CDO is possible using the CDO Legacy Mode. While this supports models that are not ported to CDO it has some performance implications.

You can activate the legacy mode like this:

```
CDOUtil.setLegacyModeDefault(true);
CDOTransaction transaction2 = session.openTransaction();
```

More information can be found here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDO/Legacy_Mode

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply :) :). I will try out with this change and soon will discuss about the results and my observations. Also thanks for the link.